# Bounding $\left|\sum_{\nu=n+1}^{\infty}a_\nu cos(\nu x)\right|$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, trigonometric-series

I'm reading Zygmund's Trigonometric Series (precisely Lemma 6.6 of chapter 12), and I'm struggling to understand the following detail. $(a_n)$ here is a sequence of positive numbers and decreasing. Also, $0<x<\pi$.

By using a corollary of summation by parts (he explicitly refers to that result, 2.3 of chapter 1) , he states that $$\left|\sum_{\nu=n+1}^{\infty}a_\nu cos(\nu x)\right|\leq \frac{\pi a_n}{x} $$

I really can't see how he gets this inequality. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there some restriction on x? Positive? if x is negative that seems impossible..

Comment: Yes Eduardo, $0<x<\pi$ is assumed  in the proof.

Comment: Ok, so the non trivial part is to proof that the partial sums of cos(vx) < pi/x. I'll try to sketch an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, applying the summation by parts on $\left|\sum_{v=n+1}^\infty a_v \cos(vx)\right|$ it implies:
$$
\left|\sum_{v=n+1}^\infty a_v \cos(vx) \right| \leq a_{n+1}\cdot h 
$$
Where $h$ is a bound for the partial sums of $\sum_{v=n+1}^N \cos(vx)$.
$$
\sum_{v=n+1}^N \cos(vx) = \sum_{v=0}^M \cos(vx + (n+1)x) = \frac{\sin\frac{(M+1) x}{2} \cdot \cos\left((n+1)x + \frac{M x}{2}\right)}{\sin\frac{x}{2}} \leq \frac{1}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}
$$
For now we get
$$
\left|\sum_{v=n+1}^\infty a_v \cos(vx) \right| \leq \frac{a_{n+1}}{\sin \frac{x}{2}} \leq \frac{a_{n}}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}
$$

In the case were $\pi/2>x>0$, we have bounds $x>\sin(x)>x/(\pi/2)$ (that can be easily seen from the graph of $\sin(x)$ or, more formally, through Jensen's inequality), thus:
$$
\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)>\frac{\left(x/2\right)}{\pi/2} = \frac{x}{\pi}
$$
So,
$$
\left|\sum_{v=n+1}^\infty a_v \cos(vx) \right| \leq  \frac{a_{n}}{\sin \frac{x}{2}} \leq \frac{a_{n}}{x/\pi}=\frac{\pi~a_{n}}{x}
$$

Comment: I get a better idea now about what's happening, thank you very much!

Comment: @mark_hoffman just made an edit with the missing last bit =)